# The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. (Using resource)

Tags: php, laravel

I have saw this issue couple of times but not in this exact form.

Here's my: **edit.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.korisnici.update', ['korisnik' => $korisnik->id]) }}" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{method_field('PUT')}}
    @foreach($uloge as $uloga)
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" name="uloge[]" value="{{ $uloga->id }}" 
            {{ $korisnik->hasRole($uloga->naziv_tipa)?'checked':'' }}>
            <label>{{ $uloga->naziv_tipa }}</label>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Ažuriraj</button>
</form>
```

My controller: **KorisniciController.php**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
        if (Auth::user()->id == $id) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.korisnici.index');
        }

        $korisnik = User::find($id);
        $korisnik->roles()->sync($request->uloge);

    return redirect()->route('admin.korisnici.index');
}
```

And my **web.app**

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth', 'roles.admin'])->name('admin.')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('/korisnici', 'KorisniciController')->except(['show', 'create', 'store']);
});
```

php artisan route:list returns

```
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                              | Name                    | Action                                                                 | Middleware               |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                                |                         | Closure                                                                | web                      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin                            |                         | Closure                                                                | web,auth,roles.admin     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/korisnici                  | admin.korisnici.index   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\KorisniciController@index                   | web,auth,roles.admin     |
|        | DELETE    | admin/korisnici/{korisnici}      | admin.korisnici.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\KorisniciController@destroy                 | web,auth,roles.admin     |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/korisnici/{korisnici}      | admin.korisnici.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\KorisniciController@update                  | web,auth,roles.admin     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/korisnici/{korisnici}/edit | admin.korisnici.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\KorisniciController@edit                    | web,auth,roles.admin     |
```

Comment: What does `php artisan route:list` return?

Comment: @kerbholz I have edited and added route list that I'm getting in return.

Comment: Try changing the parameter name to  korisnici instead korisnik in your form route('admin.korisnici.update', ['korisnici' => $korisnik->id])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route is expecting parameter korisnici, but you pass korisnik

Actually, you don't need to specify the key at all, just pass the model to the route

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.korisnici.update', $korisnik) }}"
```

Comment: correct, for a single parameter you don't have to pass an array, the helper ends up wrapping it in a array internally anyway

Comment: @lagbox thats not the reason for removing the array.  Laravel will automatically pull the route key binding from the model and insert the correct parameter.  Further, If a key value pair is provided, and the key name does not match the name of the parameter in the route then the key and value are passed as query string values.  This then means that the post is short of the model ID and throws the error because there is no PUT route for just `admin/korisnici/`

Comment: right, this is why you use the correct parameter names :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be your case or not, but it's happened with me once and the solution was clear the route cache:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: Already tried that one since similar issues were opened before. Didn't work unfortunately.